# Showing and adding arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a problem relating to arrays in Windows Form Application.
The problem is that I don't know if it's possible to do math with them, and if so how?

Let's say that I have declared something like this `int[] price = new int[] { 10, 12, 7, 11 };`
What I want to do with these arrays is to add them together depending on if the required `checkbox` is checked.

[image: This is my form (godisForm)]
'

Let's say if I check the first and third checkbox, the first and third array should add up.

I want the sum of the checked arrays where it says "Kostar : [0]".
The output label is named: `kostarLbl`.

I have tried it myself, but I know far too little to acually solve it :(

If you have any questions, feel free to ask them!

Comment: Look at linq Sum() and then post what you have tried.

Comment: Showing your UI does nothing for us, we need to see the code that drives the UI.

Comment: I don't really have anything behind the UI except for the if loop that requires you to atleast check one checkbox

Comment: Can't you do a mere foreach loop? D: `int total = 0; foreach (int i in price) total += i; Kostar.Value = total;`

Comment: Hi Hugo - welcome to StackOverflow! You will find that when posting questions, you will be far more likely to receive answers from other users when you post the code that you have tried or the research that you have done, as it shows us that you have attempted to put the work in to solve the problem yourself, before asking us to do it for you. Good luck, and happy coding! :)

Comment: Post what you've tried. You can use basic `for` or `foreach` loop constructs, and as @MikeCheel mentioned, LINQ's `Sum()` will do it.

Comment: The questions on this website need to be understandable in english, I don't see the relevance between your checkboxes and your array.

Comment: Why not use [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to answer this without seeing your code, but I think what you are asking is that you need to add up only certain elements of the array, depending on which checkboxes are checked.

To do this, on the button click event, you would have something like this:

```
int total = 0;
if(checkbox1.checked){
    total += price[0];
}
if(checkbox2.checked){
    total += price[1];
}
kostarLbl.Text = total.toString();
etc...
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but I need to be able to add multiple arrays up (depending if more than one is checked). UPDATE: Never mind, figured it out! Thank you :)

Comment: What you can do then, is use the code I provided to check if the checkbox is checked, and then use the code to sum arrays from the previous answers on the specific arrays associated with that certain checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above comment, LINQ provides some useful extension methods on Lists and collections.  You will need a reference to the System.Linq namespace if I am not mistaken.

You could call the .Sum() function on your price array to get the sum of the items in your array:

```
 int[] price = new int[] { 10, 12, 7, 11 };

 if (chkKostar.Checked) {
      var total = price.Sum();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global variable which will represent total sum.

```
int sum = 0; //global variable for whole sum
```

And declare arrays for each option, for example:

```
int[] CheckBoxNameArray = new int[] { 10, 12, 7, 11 }; //as your price array, but yo uhave 4 such arrays
```

Then add for each checkbox such an method handling checked changed event. (just double click on checkbox in editor)

```
private void CheckBoxName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.CheckBoxName.Checked)
    {
        sum += CheckBoxNameArray.Sum();
    }
    else 
    {
        sum -= CheckBoxNameArray.Sum();        
    }
    kostarLbl.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is also a good method if you wanted to automatically change the label without having to press a button to do the calculation.